# iOS Background processing

Tags: iphone, event-handling, background

In an iPhone application

Is there a way to register an event handler when the application is not running.
The reason I ask is I want to upload data from the device but only if this is not going to cause a problem to the user (the conditions may not always be good while the application is running).

I don't want data to go over the cellular network (only WiFi). I would prefer it only happen when the device is plugged into power (so it does not affect batter life). Preferably not when another application is consuming a lot of CPU bandwidth (don't want to slow other apps down).

Also is there a concise list of events (if any) that are produced by the OS?

Comment: As far as a list of events the OS is running (like a task manager), there is nothing you can access. Also, if the app is not running, the only real way to interact from "it" is from push notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the application isn't running, then there is no way for it to register a handler.

Here is an interesting discussion about the system events.
http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=453638
In short, even if you had the list, you can't do anything with the information.

Answer (score 1):

Register your application to run in background, and inside [applicationDidEnterBackground](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) (or applicationWillEnterBackground) delegate event call your method to upload data.

To check if wifi is active please refer [Network Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SimpleReach/Listings/Read_Me_About_SimpleReach_txt.html)